# List of URLs to "convert" to other URLs

Tags: php

I have certain URLs which I want to convert to another, for example,
anything that starts with `/some/url/`:

`/some/url/a/b/`, `/some/url/a/222/111` will be considered as `/some/url/`

Currently what I do is to have an array of URLs I know I want to "convert":

```
public function get_converted_url($request)
{
    $full_url = $request->input('url');
    $urls_to_convert = ['/some/url/', '/other/url'];
    $parsed_url = parse_url($full_url);
    $path = $parsed_url['path'];
    foreach ($urls_to_convert as $url_to_convert) {
        if (strpos($path, $url_to_convert, 0) !== false) {
            return $url_to_convert;
        }
    }
    return $path;   
}
```

Is there a better way to do it? Or, do I have issues with the above? I used `strpos` and not `str_contains` because I wanted that the URL will match with the right order.

So that it won't match `/some/url/to/match` if I get `/url/to/` for example

Comment: The second argument of [strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos) should be a string, not an array. I think you got into this mess because you of the names you chose for your variables. For instance, `$url = parse_url($full_url);` makes little sense. Better would be: `$url_components = parse_url($url);`. Using comprehensible names, that actually relate to what a variable contains, can help to make code easier to understand, thereby preventing bugs.

Comment: I think you might have edited your code for this question. Cutting it down to its bare essentials. By doing so you introduced some bugs. Basically the code doesn't do what you say it does, and you didn't test it. When we review code we have to be critical, otherwise we won't be of help to you. So next time, take a bit more care when asking a question, and make sure the code works and makes sense.

Comment: you are correct, sorry. The mistake was that it needed to be `$url_to_convert` and not `$url`, I edited it now. Yes I copied the bare essentials manually and therefore the mistakes

Comment: OK, that's slightly better, but the code still doesn't make much sense. Note that you still overwrite the `$url` array. I know what you're trying to do, but you don't actually do that. Please only publish _working code_ in your question. Test it, prove to yourself it works, and that it results in something sensible that we can understand.

Comment: Sorry again :) Now I think I fixed everything

Comment: No you didn't. Your function doesn't return anything. You really should test your code, not just assume it will work. Testing is easy with online tools like [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/) or [phptester.net](http://phptester.net/). Just drop your code in it, fake some arguments and see what it returns.

Comment: Making mistakes is human, I make mistakes all the time.  We are fallible, so we need checking. I also really don't like the function name `my_method`, what's that? We _hate_ pseudo-code here on Code Review.

Comment: because I only copied the bare essentials at the beginning, I wanted to then make it look closer to the real function and wrapped it in some arbitrary name . But now, hopefully, it looks better and fits more to Code Review Stack Exchange :). Basically this function returns the first match it finds, and if not it returns the original path

Comment: Yes, this is a lot better. See my [code test](https://3v4l.org/MSNCm). Notice the first case? I don't think that's what you want to happen. Since you now showed that this is a method in a class, I would strongly advice not to put the `$urls_to_convert` array in this method. Either make it an argument, or define it as a constant of the class.

Comment: What about /off/some/url/a/b/? should it be recognized as /some/url/?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware o wow I didn't realize it doesn't work like that. I thought that using the position flag at `0` it will match by order. Now I realized that it simply means it starts looking at position `0`. and that's why it matched /test/some/url/ as `/some/url/` which is not good. Your Common Sense - No, I want the URLs in the array to be matched by the order they are written

Comment: I think the lesson you should have learned by now is that [testing is everything](https://toolsqa.com/software-testing/istqb/why-is-testing-necessary/).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware indeed :D

Comment: Update: I changed it to `str_starts_with` and it seems to work better :)

Comment: Keep in mind this Code Review is not stack overflow, we do not debug code and we do not want to see the minimum reproducible code.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with this function is it does quite a lot.
It parses input. Why? What if you will need to use it with some other source?
It defines an array of canonical urls taken from nowhere
It does the actual job of canonizing urls.

I would leave only the code the does the actual job.

```
function canonize_url($url)
{
    $path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    foreach ($this->canonical_urls as $url_to_convert) {
        if (str_starts_with($path, $url_to_convert)) {
            return $url_to_convert;
        }
    }
    return $path;   
}
```

I am assuming that the function belongs to some class and hence the list of canonical urls is better to be made a class variable.

`str_starts_with()` function is used here, which is rather recent. In case your PHP doesn't support it, you can easily create a userland implementation.